# "warning: type 'id <UIApplicationDelegate>' does not conform to the 'UITabBarControllerDelegate' protocol"?

Tags: ios, core-data, casting

[image]

Hey Guys,

Anyone have any idea why I'm getting the warning pictured in the attached image?
Right above the code in question is a comment from the code I got from "More iPhone 3 Development" which is an Apress book. The author trying to tell me something about typecasting to quiet the warning but I don't know how.

> "warning: type 'id
>   ' does not
>   conform to the
>   'UITabBarControllerDelegate' protocol"

I'm not using a tab bar or it's delegate anywhere in my app.
I get the same warning in both places where I use:

```
AV_MonitorAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

to get a pointer to my app delegate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try casting it to the appropriate type before the assignment,

```
AV_MonitorAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AV_MonitorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: That did it. I love it when it's simple. Thank you.